# Azure App Service Set Custom ConnectionTimeout in ApplicationHost.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, timeout, azure-web-app-service, applicationhost

On our ASP.NET MVC website hosted on Azure App Service we'd like to force a timeout for requests that take longer than 15 seconds. Here's a simple action that always takes longer than 15 seconds (i.e. infinite loop) that we've been testing with...

```
    public ActionResult TimeoutTest()
    {
        var i = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            i++;
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
```

By default, if I do a GET on that action in a browser, I'll get a "500 - The request timed out" error after two minutes, which agrees with [the "connectionTimeout" default setting in the webLimits section of ApplicationHost.config](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/weblimits).

So...unless I'm mistaken, it should be enough to change this connectionTimeout value to 15 seconds. To do this, I understand one needs to use a transform-based approach for the ApplicationHost.config file (XDT), as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2015/03/03/making-changes-to-the-applicationhost-config-on-azure-websites/).

I did this with the following applicationHost.xdt file...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<system.applicationHost>
      <webLimits xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionTimeout)" connectionTimeout="00:00:15"/>
</system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

...after which I added the file in the right place (d:/home/site/applicationHost.xdt). I restarted my site and saw in the logs that the transform was successfully applied:

```
2016-04-20T08:40:44 Start 'site' site extension transform
2016-04-20T08:40:44 StartSection Executing SetAttributes (transform line 4, 18)
2016-04-20T08:40:44 on /configuration/system.applicationHost/webLimits
2016-04-20T08:40:44 Applying to 'webLimits' element (no source line info)
2016-04-20T08:40:44 Set 'connectionTimeout' attribute
2016-04-20T08:40:44 Set 1 attributes
2016-04-20T08:40:44 EndSection Done executing SetAttributes
2016-04-20T08:40:44 Successful 'D:\home\site\applicationHost.xdt' site extension transform
2016-04-20T08:40:44 sandboxproc.exe complete successfully. Ellapsed = 316.00 ms
```

[Edit]: I have also checked the applicationhost.config directly after the transform, and the new value is there:

```
    ...
    </sites>
    <webLimits connectionTimeout="00:00:15" />
  </system.applicationHost>
  <system.webServer>
    <asp>
    ...
```

Despite all this, if I hit my action method above again, it still times out after two minutes instead of 15 seconds.

**My question:** Does anybody know why this timeout setting isn't being respected?

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427635/applicationhost-config-azure-web-app), which looks like it took exactly the same approach (and seemed to work?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using executionTimeout instead, through the Web.Config?

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="30" />
    <compilation debug="false" />
</system.web>
```

For a MVC project, you should add the following code to force the value to be applied to the request:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetType().GetField("_timeoutState", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, 1);
```

If you want every request to respect this setting, you can create an action filter:

```
public class Timeoutter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetType().GetField("_timeoutState", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, 1);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Add register it in the RegisterGlobalFilters method called in the Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new Timeoutter());
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Please see:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://forums.asp.net/p/1715081/4723882.aspx?Re+web+config+executionTimeout+not+working+in+ASP+NET+MVC
- [.NET Execution Timeout Not Taking Effect in an MVC Web Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657381/net-execution-timeout-not-taking-effect-in-an-mvc-web-project)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm aware of that one too. It's also set to 15 seconds and doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: I've added more details above.